# Finding the sum of digits of a large number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

[image]

Can anyone help me in finding the sum of digits without manual multiplication?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines . Warning: it doesn't work for exponents.

Comment: Hint: $5^6=9\times 1736+1$

Comment: To summarize, the sum of digits of a number will have the same remainder when divided by nine as the original number.  The sum of the digits of the sum of the digits of ... repeated until being left with a single digit will be very simply *the remainder* of the number when dividing by nine.  Very nice patterns emerge when looking at this as it relates to exponents.  In particular, if we were to only write the remainders and not the full numbers themselves, we get $5^0,5^1,5^2,5^3,5^4,5^5,5^6,5^7,5^8,5^9,\dots$ give remainders $1,5,7,8,4,2,1,5,7,8,4,2,1,\dots$ and this repeats with period $6$

Comment: So, the question becomes, not necessarily *how many times* did we repeat which is irrelevant to us, but rather, at what point in the repetition are we when talking about $5^{1!+2!+3!+4!}$?  We could just as easily have been talking about $5^{1!+2!+3!+4!+\dots+99999!+1000000!}$ and the problem wouldn't have been any more difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to compute $$5\cdot5^2\cdot5^6\cdot5^{24}\pmod9$$

We have $$\begin{align}
5^2&=25\equiv-2\pmod9\\
5^6&=(5^2)^3\equiv(-2)^3\equiv-8\equiv1\pmod9\\
5^{24}&=(5^6)^4\equiv1^4\equiv1\pmod9
\end{align}$$

Take it from here.

Comment: Also $5^6\equiv1\pmod9$ by Euler's theorem